# Exception thrown: Read access violation when calling method front

Tags: c++

When i try to take the first item from the queue, i have error.

> Exception thrown: Read access violation.
> ** std :: deque <int, std :: allocator > :: front ** (...) returned 0xDDDDDDE9.

At the time of the error, the queue is not empty

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
int total;
queue<int> ox;
mutex mtx, mtx1;
void push(int x) {
   mtx1.lock();
   ox.push(x);
   mtx1.unlock();
}
bool pop(int x) {
   if (ox.size() == 0) this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
   if (ox.size() != 0) {
      mtx.lock();
      x = ox.front();
      ox.pop();
      mtx.unlock();
      return true;
   }
   if (ox.size() == 0) {
      return false;
   }
   return false;
}
void producer() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 4; i++) push(1);
}
void consumer() {

   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 4; i++) {
      int k;
      if (pop(k)) sum += k;
   }
   total += sum;

}

int main()
{
  thread th1(producer);
  thread th2(consumer);
  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  cout << total;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) used by visual studio to denote freed heap memory. At a guess `ox` is a member of an object and that object has been deleted. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your edit is still not a [mre]

Comment: Now it matches.

Comment: Why are you using two different mutexes for push and pop? What is the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a separate `std::mutex` for each thread which means effectively you have no mutex at all. You need to use the same mutex for both threads.

You also have a typo in your `pop` function, it should be `bool pop(int& x)`.

You shouldn't really be calling `mtx.lock()` and `mtx.unlock()` directly, it is much better to make use of `std::unique_lock` (or one of the other locks defined in the standard library) instead which ensures the mutex is always unlocked when it goes out of scope, e.g:

```
void push(int x) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    ox.push(x);
}
bool pop(int& x) {
    if (ox.size() == 0) this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    if (ox.size() != 0) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        x = ox.front();
        ox.pop();
        return true;
    }
    if (ox.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have to use mutex when querying queue size.

Comment: @Harry strictly yes, but I think in this case it'll work without

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
long long total;
queue<int> ox;
mutex mtx;
void push(int x) {
   mtx.lock();
   ox.push(x);
   mtx.unlock();
}
bool pop(int& x) {
  mtx.lock();
   if (ox.size() == 0) this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
   if (ox.size() != 0) {
      x = ox.front();
      ox.pop();
      mtx.unlock();
      return true;
   }

    mtx.unlock();
   return false;
}
void producer() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 4; i++) push(1);
}
void consumer() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 4; i++) {
      int k;
      if (pop(k)) total += k;
   }
}

int main()
{
  thread th1(producer);
  thread th2(consumer);
  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  cout << total;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using reference variable in wrong way. Replace it with pointer.